# Can't Sum Column On Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a B column filled with IF statements which render a number based on if the "IF" statement is true. Currently the B column is filled with numbers in B2-B19, and I want to sum all the numbers to get a total. But the SUM isn't working, it's not identifying the cells as numbers and is rendering 0. I suspect it's due to the cells having the IF statements written but the cells clearly are numbers. I have tried changing the formatting on the B column to Numbers, but it doesn't make a difference.

The formula in one cell is:

=IF(Generator!C5="2 Bathrooms", "22.50",IF(Generator!C5="3 Bathrooms", "45",IF(Generator!C5="4 Bathrooms", "67.50",IF(Generator!C5="5 Bathrooms", "90", IF(Generator!C5="6 Bathrooms", "112.50",)))))

Kind of stuck here.

Here is the google sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11mfR75ItWUE6SDRJN0qBJVEXYtQbJQOr7V9jAxXWffg/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks for the help!

I tried to use the =SUM(B2:B19) to get the total but it just gave me 0.

Comment: can you share the formula with the `IF` statements? They are probably returning text values, ie, `"7"` instead of `7`

Comment: You are going to need to show the contents of your sheet. Either directly in your question or a link to a shared file.

Comment: Sure, one cell is: =IF(Generator!C5="2 Bathrooms", "22.50",IF(Generator!C5="3 Bathrooms", "45",IF(Generator!C5="4 Bathrooms", "67.50",IF(Generator!C5="5 Bathrooms", "90", IF(Generator!C5="6 Bathrooms", "112.50",)))))

Comment: @ADOGG408 Please edit your question to show that, rather than adding a comment.

Comment: Your formula has an extra comma before the final brackets. That isn't right, surely?

Comment: Your google sheet doesn't have access...

Answer (score 0):

Please check the format of the cells where formula of IF is mentioned and convert the format to numbers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your formulas are returning text strings rather than numbers. If you want to return numbers, you have to remove the double quotes, so edit your formulas to:

```cpp
=IF(Generator!C5="2 Bathrooms",22.5,
   IF(Generator!C5="3 Bathrooms",45,
     IF(Generator!C5="4 Bathrooms",67.5,
       IF(Generator!C5="5 Bathrooms",90,
         IF(Generator!C5="6 Bathrooms",112.5,)))))
```

However, since you are always comparing the same value `Generator!C5`, I recommend using the [`SWITCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013690?hl=en) function:

```cpp
=SWITCH(Generator!C5,
        "2 Bathrooms",22.5,
        "3 Bathrooms",45,
        "4 Bathrooms",67.5,
        "5 Bathrooms",90,
        "6 Bathrooms",112.5,)
```

Since the value per bathroom increases linearly, you can also use:

```cpp
=22.5*(LEFT(Generator!C5)-1)
```